# Sequelize/Postgres - how to update each row individually on migrate?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have lots of records in my postgres. (using sequelize to communicate)

I want to have a migrate script, but due to locking, I have to do each change as atomic as possible.

So I don't want to `selectAll` and then modify and then `saveAll`.

In mongo I have `forEach` cursor which allows me to update a record, save it and only then move to the next one.

Anything similar in sequelize/postgres?

Currently, I am doing that in my code - getting the IDs, then for each performing a query.

```
return migration.runOnAllUpdates((record)=>{
    record.change = 'new value';
    return record.save()
 });
```

where `runOnAllUpdates` will simply give me records one by one.